# Accessing session variable in datatable editor

Tags: php, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I would like to set up database credentials dynamically in the application lifecycle. Since I could not do it from the class function where am calling my editor autoloader I have opted to edit the .config file of the datatable editor to this

```
require_once('../functions/functions.php');

//get db credentials
$db_credentials = get_db_credentials($_SESSION['MY_DATA']['tenant_uuid']);

$sql_details = array(
            "type" => "Mysql",
            "user" => $db_credentials['datastore_db_username'],
            "pass" => $db_credentials['datastore_db_password'],
            "db"   => $db_credentials['datastore_db_name'],
            "host" => $db_credentials['datastore_db_host'],
            "dsn"  => "", 
            "port" => "",
        );
```

However going by my logs it seems I cannot access the session variable

`$_SESSION['MY_DATA']['tenant_uuid']`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you start session_start in your code?

Comment: Yes I have it. I have included DataTables.php in my class file that calls the editor and the session is visible there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. All I needed to do is to include the ***DataTables\Database*** namespace in the function file and proceed to creating a new database instance. Changing globals in a function is quite tricky.

No need to get messy with editing the config.php file.

Final solution:

```
   use
       DataTables\Database,
       DataTables\Editor,
       DataTables\Editor\Field,
       DataTables\Editor\Format,
       DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
       DataTables\Editor\Options,
       DataTables\Editor\Upload,
       DataTables\Editor\Validate;
```

In the function

```
$db_credentials = get_db_credentials($_SESSION['MY_DATA']['tenant_uuid']);

$sql_details = array(
    "type" => "Mysql",
    "user" => $db_credentials['datastore_db_username'],
    "pass" => $db_credentials['datastore_db_password'],
    "db"   => $db_credentials['datastore_db_name'],
    "host" => $db_credentials['datastore_db_host'],
    "dsn"  => "", 
    "port" => "",
);

$db_details = new Database( $sql_details );
```